# How to create OSGI bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, bundle

I developed a standard Java application and it's interfaces, the thing here that i'm want to put that application in OSGI bundle, i'm not familiar with OSGI at all, only the concepts of it, but about nothing in programming, i just want to learn how to put this application into a bundle but upon search i always get a full books or full references and i don't have enough time for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a `MANIFEST.MF` file which will have the bundle information like version, bundle name, the packages that are to be imported/exported, etc. The `MANIFEST.MF` file has to be placed in the `META-INF` folder of your bundle.

[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html) is a good tutorial to start you with OSGi.

Answer (score 2):

This [bndtools tutorial](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html) is probably the easiest way to get started with OSGi. If also this tutorial is too much work I actually would not even start. Though OSGi is surprisingly easy to use its concepts and requirements on your code are different then what you find in more classic Java environments.